# How do I convert a long into a char[] array in java?

Tags: java, long-integer

I'm trying to convert a long into a char array[] in java.

say you have 1125. the char array should look like this:
char[] numArray = {1, 1, 2, 5,....}; with numArray being 1000 in length

Comment: `char[] numArray = Long.toString(1125).toCharArray();`

Comment: Why would `numArray` be 1000 in length? Number has 4 digits, so array would be 4 in length. Otherwise, what values should the remaining 996 `char` values be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
char[] arrayOfNum = Long.toString(1125).toCharArray();
        System.out.println(arrayOfNum);
```

You do not need to provide the number of chars the array should have and that number should be 4, not 1000.

Comment: The program that im writing for class requires that the char array is 1000 in length because i have another constructor and im calculating big integers. that cant be stored in long or int. Thanks this helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
String strLong = Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE);
List<Character> characters = IntStream.range(0,strLong.length()).mapToObj(strLong::charAt)
       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(1000)));
Character[] numArray = characters.toArray(new Character[1000]);
```

in fact,even `Long.MAX_VALUE` has only 19 digits.